# C++ template specialization definitions shared across files

Tags: c++, templates, linker, linker-errors

I have a template class "Extra," defined in "extra.h," with a function "doSomething," and I have defined two specializations of "doSomething."  Two different functions create objects of type "Extra," each with a different type parameter, and each calls a different one of the specializations.  The two client functions, "client1" and "client2," are defined in two files, "client1.cpp" and "client2.cpp," respectively.  In a third file, "main" calls "client1" and then "client2."  Now, "client1.cpp" and "client2.cpp" both #include "extra.h."  I get a linker error that "doSomething" has (2) multiple definitions.  Naturally, if I put the defintions of "client1" and "client2" into a single source file, I do not have this problem.  Is there any way that I can preserve my arrangement of distinct files for "client1" and "client2"?  Below is my code.  Thank you!

```
// extra.h
#ifndef EXTRA_H
#define EXTRA_H

template <typename T>
class Extra
{
    public:
        Extra(T);
        ~Extra();
        T doSomething(T);
    private:
        Extra() {}
        T m_value;
};

template <typename T> Extra<T>::Extra(T input) : m_value{input} {}

template <typename T> Extra<T>::~Extra() {}

template <> int Extra<int>::doSomething(int input)
{
    return input * m_value;
}

template <> double Extra<double>::doSomething(double input)
{
    return input + m_value;
}

template <typename T> T Extra<T>::doSomething(T input)
{
    return input;
}
#endif

// client1.cpp
#include "extra.h"
#include <iostream>

void client1()
{
    std::cout << "In client1." << std::endl;
    Extra<int> extra(2);
    int res = extra.doSomething(3);
    std::cout << "Value: " << res << std::endl;
}

// client2.cpp
#include "extra.h"
#include <iostream>

void client2()
{
    std::cout << "In client2." << std::endl;
    Extra<double> extra(2.0);
    double res = extra.doSomething(2.0);
    std::cout << "Value: " << res << std::endl;
}

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

void client1();
void client2();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "In main." << std::endl;
    client1();
    client2();
    return 0;
}
```

And here, for completness, is my linker error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o client client1.cpp client2.cpp main.cpp 
duplicate symbol __ZN5ExtraIiE11doSomethingEi in:
    /var/folders/mf/jdvfkpms609206zpz8x5237r0000gn/T/client1-6fa7ed.o
    /var/folders/mf/jdvfkpms609206zpz8x5237r0000gn/T/client2-387444.o
duplicate symbol __ZN5ExtraIdE11doSomethingEd in:
    /var/folders/mf/jdvfkpms609206zpz8x5237r0000gn/T/client1-6fa7ed.o
    /var/folders/mf/jdvfkpms609206zpz8x5237r0000gn/T/client2-387444.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark your `doSomething` inline:

```
template <> inline int Extra<int>::doSomething(int input)
{
    return input * m_value;
}

template <> inline double Extra<double>::doSomething(double input)
{
    return input + m_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I had already tried that--I thought--but I had forgotten that you have to mark the definitions _inline_ and not just the declaration.

Comment: @AmittaiAviram with this proposed solution problem is fixed, right?

Comment: Yes!  Now, this was a toy example, of course, so I have to try applying it to the real case, which is much more complicated.  I guess the general principle is that you must inline every function specialization, so that the compiler will move the code into the caller, and it will no longer appear as a distinct function definition in multiple translation units.  Thanks again!

Comment: @AmittaiAviram in general `inline` is really a hint for the linker to notify that there are multiple copies of the same function are possible. When you define a function directly inside a class it's implicitly treated as inline. When you define functions inside a header file and outside of some class (like you did) you almost always have to mark them explicitly inline to avoid linker errors. Whether compiler inlines them is a different issue.